# Google Maps v2 change language

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

The problem is that the google maps retain the language it has when it was first open. For example, I have 2 activities (Activity A and Activity B). The Activity A consist of settings page where I change the language to that activity. Note that it's not the system language, but using the `Locale.setDefault()`. This successfully translates my app, no problem with the text, except the google maps language. The Activity B consists of the MapFragment where I show the map.

When I start the MapActivity on **English** language, the map shows the **English** language. When I go back to Activity A and change the language, then open again the MapActivity, the map retains the English Language as its like saving its instance from a background process.

My investigation is that, the google maps language was based on the first language the maps rendered and it will retain unless the app is completely close.

Can someone help me with this problem to change the google maps language base on the Locale set in my Settings page. What I've tried so far is to clear the cache(my app and the google services) and also destroying the fragments by activating the `useViewLifeCycleInFragments` of the `SupportMapFragment` and use the fragment life cycle.

Thanks.

**Update**

Still cant get to translate the Google Maps:

What I have tried:

1. Close the google play services process -> not working (impossible)
2. Use 2 Map Fragment -> not working, it will load same maps

Comment: If you activate "Do not keep activities" in developer options does the behavior change?

Comment: are you also changing using getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration ? 
what happens if you change language before going to activity B?

Comment: @pablobu yes in my localehelper

Comment: @SecretCoder Have you manage to find a solution? I have a similar problem. I don't want to overlay tiles as described below.

Comment: @Hollywood no solution so far, just got lucky the client consider as it is :D

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the Tile caching of google map.
What you should do is using [Tile Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay#samples) and [Tile Provider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider#field-summary)

Google put some sample for you in the links i provided.

you should get tiles by yourself and use imageloader or picaso library, then disable caching in their setups.

By doing this you always get new tiles by the local language you provided

Sample :

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlay;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlayOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileProvider;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.UrlTileProvider;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * This demonstrates how to add a tile overlay to a map.
 */
public class TileOverlayDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

/** This returns moon tiles. */
private static final String MOON_MAP_URL_FORMAT =
        "http://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw/%d/%d/%d.jpg";

private TileOverlay mMoonTiles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tile_overlay_demo);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

    TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
        @Override
        public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            // The moon tile coordinate system is reversed.  This is not normal.
            int reversedY = (1 << zoom) - y - 1;
            String s = String.format(Locale.US, MOON_MAP_URL_FORMAT, zoom, x, reversedY);
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(s);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
            return url;
        }
    };

    mMoonTiles = map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));
}

public void setFadeIn(View v) {
    if (mMoonTiles == null) {
        return;
    }
    mMoonTiles.setFadeIn(((CheckBox) v).isChecked());
}
}
```

what you should do is changing the Local in OnMapReady in Tile Provider

Comment: but the tile overlay is just image and not actually a map where i can put a polygon right?

Comment: No Bro ! It work all over the world. What you Should Do is finding the url and replace it with the URL. like this one 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x=1325&y=3143&z=13' @SecretCoder

Comment: but the db return only the lat and long and i cant use web api

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to be aware of the supported languages and to take note of language codes used as detailed in [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html).

And to do it programmatically, solution was already given in this SO post - [How to change language in android google maps v2 programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245100/how-to-change-language-in-android-google-maps-v2-programmatically).

Please let us know if it work for you too. :)

Comment: im already aware of that and also with that SO post. it is correct it change the locale but only once. when you go back and change the locale and open the map activity again, the language is still the because the map instance is not reset