# How to display Indian tamil text in android google map

Tags: android, google-maps, locale

I have used the below code but I can't display Indian tamil text in android google maps.

So if any one have any idea please help me.

```
String language= "ta_IN"; //tamil language!
Locale locale = new Locale(language);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
    config.setLocale(locale);
    getApplicationContext().createConfigurationContext(config);
}else { //deprecated
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245100/how-to-change-language-in-android-google-maps-v2-programmatically

Comment: I had used it already but there is no change, For example the above code is working for china, japan and many other but not on tamil....

Comment: @Jaymurugan ok.. let me check other tries

Comment: There is a bug report for this: issuetracker.google.com/issues/36823099